# How to pass the object being iterated to JS controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm iterating over a list of Stores(Account) to display all the Stores assigned to an individuals. What I want to achieve is, from the list of Stores if one of list items (Store) is clicked/touched, it should display the details of that account. I have an Array of Store(Account) as an attribute in the component I'm iterating in.

```
<aura:attribute name="stores" type="Account[]"/>  
<aura:iteration items="{!v.stores}" var="store">
    <c:IndirectStoreCard store="{!store}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

As you can see, I have created nested component(c:IndirectStoreCard) which encapsulate all the details of a store. My question is, how do I pass, the selected record i.e.Store to the JS controller. I know how to pass one of the fields (say, Id) to controller using anchor tag, but that would required me to query the other fields from the database and I don't want another database trip, simply because I already have all the data.So, I want pass the entire record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured another way to achieve this. There is no need to create a child component:

```
    <aura:attribute name="stores" type="Account[]"/> 
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.stores}" var="store" indexVar="idx">
    <div class="slds-card"  data-record="{!idx}"  onclick="{!c.goToStoreDetail}">
        <header class="slds-card__header slds-grid grid--flex-spread">    
            <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-truncate">{!store.Name}</h2>
        </header>            
    </div>                                                
</aura:iteration>
```

As you can see, I have used indexVar attribute in the iteration. I then use the index values in the data attribute of Div. Now in the JS Controller you can use the following code to retrieve the record based on the index.

```
     var selectedItem = event.currentTarget; // Get the target object
     var index = selectedItem.dataset.record; // Get its value i.e. the index
     var selectedStore = component.get("v.stores")[index]; // Use it retrieve the store record
```

Use console.log to verify the results.

Answer (score 4):

When the nested component(c:IndirectStoreCard) is clicked, it fires a component event with a parameter(the selected record).

IndirectStoreCard.cmp:

```
<aura:attribute name="store" type="Account" />
<aura:registerEvent name="onClick" type="c:messageEvt" />
<div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="{!c.clickStore}">
  <p>{!v.store.Name}</p>
</div>
```

IndirectStoreCardController.js:

```
clickStore: function(component, event, helper) {
  var cmpEvt = component.getEvent("onClick");
  cmpEvt.setParams({
    "store": component.get("v.store")
  }).fire();
}
```

Then the parent component is

```
<aura:attribute name="stores" type="Account[]"/>  
<aura:iteration items="{!v.stores}" var="store">
  <c:IndirectStoreCard store="{!store}" onClick="{!c.clickStore}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

JS controller:

```
clickStore: function(component, event, helper) {
  var store = event.getParam("store");
  console.log(store);
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me. When I click on list item, nothing happens. I must be doing something wrong. Are you sure, the event you are firing from the IndirectStoreCard, doesn't require a handler in the parent? Any input on how can I debug the code?

Comment: I also set an alert on IndirectStoreCard controller to check if the event is getting fired. But it's not reaching there.

Comment: If you want to write as below:  

`<c:IndirectStoreCard store="{!store}" />`


you need to add a handler in the parent component:<br/>

`<aura:handler name="onClick" event="c:messageEvt" action="{!c.clickStore}"/>`

When you set an alert at the first line, does a popup window open?

And you try to check whether _cmpEvt_ is not null.
If _cmpEvt_ is null, then you will make a mistake in the name of aura:registerEvent.

Comment: I set an alert on IndirectStoreCardController.js t to check if cmpEvent is null, but no pop up comes up. What I feel is, the event is not fired, because when I click on the list item, nothing happens, nothing. I also verified the name of aura:registerEvent to where I'm accessing it. It's all correct. Please find all the code here: http://codepaste.net/95uxp5

Comment: You try to change `<div class="slds-card" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="{!c.goToStoreDetail}">` to `<div class="slds-card" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="{!c.goToStoreDetail}">`. Not "onClick" but "onclick"

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link whether it is useful

[How to Navigate to the record/get the record id in <Aura:iteration>](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115663/how-to-navigate-to-the-record-get-the-record-id-in-auraiteration)

If you still have problem, provide snippet of your code