# How to fetch the value inside a list item(not having an id since created dynamically) in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, dependent-picklist, id, iteration

I am creating a a list using aura:iteration:

```
<aura:iteration var="pf" items="{!v.family}" indexVar="ind">
  <li class="slds-dropdown__item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitemradio" onclick="{!c.prodShow}">
          <p class="slds-truncate">
              <c:svg ariaHidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS102/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check"/>
              {!pf}</p>
      </a>
  </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

Now, when someone clicks on each of these `<li>` I want to get the value of {!pf} on click on that `<li>`. Currently, I am not being able to do so since I do not have any ID specific for each `<li>`.

Could anyone please tell me how to do this? I need this value to populate another dependent picklist on-click of this one.

Comment: Have look at this [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115663/how-to-navigate-to-the-record-get-the-record-id-in-auraiteration/115674), it address your problem

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't find my solution in this answer. Could you please elaborate Praveen? I don't see a way to set ids from each ' <li>' and accessing them in the helper.

Comment: i have updated my answer which includes two possible way to access the clicked record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this in two ways:

1.you could do set the `data-index` instead of `id` to hold the index in the component and access the clicked value using the id's value in the controller:(based on CharlesT comment)

```
<aura:iteration var="pf" items="{!v.family}" indexVar="ind">
  <li class="slds-dropdown__item">
      <a data-index="{!ind}" href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitemradio" onclick="{!c.prodShow}">
          <p class="slds-truncate">
              <c:svg ariaHidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS102/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check"/>
              {!pf}</p>
      </a>
  </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

In the controller.js

```
({
 prodShow: function(cmp, ev) {
        var index = event.target.dataset.index;
        console.log(cmp.get("v.family")[index]);
    }
})
```

2.you need to break the component into two : Event Driven Way

For instance,

1.ListCmp - (fetches the data) -> Parent Component

2.ListItemCmp - (displays each record) -> Child component

And use the Event driven way to pass the clicked record from the ListItemCmp to the ListCmp.

**ListCmp.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="family" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="sendRecordToParent" event="c:selectedRecordEvt" action="{!c.gotRecordFromChild}" />

        <aura:iteration var="pf" items="{!v.family}" indexVar="ind">
            <c:ListItemCmp item="{!pf}" /> 
        </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**ListCmpController.js**

```
({
 editRecord : function(cmp, ev) {
        var selectedValue = event.getParam("record");
        console.log(selectedValue);
    }
})
```

This is an Component level event you should create, which carries the data to the parent.

**selectedRecordEvt.evt**

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT">
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

**ListItemCmp.cmp**

```
<aura:compoent>
<aura:attribute name="item" type="String"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="sendRecordToParent" type="c:selectedRecordEvt"/>

      <li class="slds-dropdown__item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitemradio" onclick="{!c.sendToParent}">
              <p class="slds-truncate">
                  <c:svg ariaHidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right--x-small" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS102/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check"/>
                  {!v.item}</p>
          </a>
      </li>
</aura:component>
```

**ListItemCmpController.js**

```
({
    sendToParent : function(component, event, helper) {
        var event = component.getEvent("sendRecordToParent");
        event.setParams({
            'record':component.get("v.item")
        });
        event.fire();
})
```

Also, the OP's solution :

```
var prodFam = event.currentTarget.childNodes[0].innerText;
```

would also work if the element exist in the same namespace in the component.

Comment: Thank you so much for your extremely elaborated explanation. I am new to lightning. Hence, it was great to understand two different possible solutions. However, what I did is simply this.

var prodFam = event.currentTarget.childNodes[0].innerText;

I could get hold of the text inside the <li> perfectly. Could you tell me if this method has any drawbacks in your opinion?

Comment: Your code wont work in Org with locker service enabled

Comment: More info about Locker Service and be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html)

Comment: Getting `innerText` will work fine under Locker as long as the element was created by a component in your namespace. In regards to the first way, it would be a lousy practice to store a small integer value in the HTML `id` attribute because that attribute must be unique across the whole page. Instead you can store it in a `data-` attribute such as `data-index="4"`. You can then get these attributes out using `element.dataset.index`.

Comment: I totally agree with you @CharlesT . I have updated the answer.

Comment: So in that case since i am creating the list items from the lightning components, will I be able to access `innerText` ? Or will locker service restrict that too?