# jQuery(elem).index() doesn't work in LEX? How can one get index of element in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I get used to use jQuery when I develop Visualforce.
Looks like jQuery doesn't work with Lightning.
I am trying to get index of < tr> element clicked in table element using Ligtnening.

I would assume this code to work

```
jQuery(event.currentTarget).index()
```

but this returns -1. In Visualforce

```
jQuery(this).index()
```

returns me index of current tr element.

I don't want to use data-index property because I don't want to make this more complicated and create additional model around SObject record which I don't really need here.

Currently I am thinking about some code like this

```
var trs = $('table.labels').find('tr');
        var index;
        for ( var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++ ) {
            if ( trs[i] == event.currentTarget ) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
```

but it looks to me really ugly and cumbersome.

Does anyone know any better and more elegant solution?

Thanks.

Comment: To use data-index, you don't need to modify your model if you are using `aura:iteration`.Check this [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/127599/20830).How are you generating the table?

Comment: trying to adopt that approach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually had aura:iteration tag like this

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.projects}" var="project">
<tr onclick="{!c.labelClick}">
<td title="{! project.Name }">
{! project.Name }
</td>
</tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

One more guy (besides of Praveen) also suggested to use indexVar and data-index.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.projects}" var="project"indexVar="index">
<tr data-index="{!index}"  onclick="{!c.labelClick}">
<td title="{! project.Name }">
{! project.Name }
</td>
</tr>
</aura:iteration>
enter code here
```

so this helps to use some code like this:

```
var index = event.currentTarget.dataset.index;
```

The only drawback of this approach is that data-index property is String, instead of Integer, but looks like it still works even being String at least for my case.

Comment: I would if I could. When I try it shows red alert and says:
"You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: Ok Patlatus, Please mark it after 2 days. Thanks

Comment: Using data is an excellent approach.